# Entity framework not inserting values into nullable datetime field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I can't save values into two nullable columns.

This is the entity I'm saving:

```
  nquote_orderheaders header = new nquote_orderheaders()
            {
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                SendDate = DateTime.Now,
                SentByUser = accountInfo.Username,
                CreatedByUser = accountInfo.Username,
                QuoteOrderNumber = tempQuoteNumber,
                IMCustomerNumber = resellerInfo.CustomerNo,
                CustomerEmail = accountInfo.Username,
                CustomerName = resellerInfo.CustomerName,
                UserComment = "",
                StatusId = 1,
                CustomerId = data.CustomerId,
                ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)
            };
```

The SendDate and ExpirationDate fields are nullable Datetimes. They end up null in the database.

I'm using MySql with MySqlConnector 6.5.4. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: IS CreatedDate end with out nullable.

Comment: Can you paste in your Entity class?

Comment: I don't know about `MySqlConnector`, maybe it's _very_ picky about matching types. You may try to set nullable DateTime values: `SendDate = new Nullable<DateTime>(DateTime.Now)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast `DateTime.Now` to the Nullable just like the following code:

```
CreatedDate = DateTime.Now as DateTime?,
```

or using longer form:

```
CreatedDate = DateTime.Now as Nullable<DateTime>,
```

Comment: Still saves a null date.